# Please install Android target "android-19"

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2013

When i try to run visual studio apache cordove project, i get error "Please install Android target "android-19".".
How can i add android-19 in visual studio 2013

Comment: this issue got resolved by just restarting my system.

Answer (score 0):

just go to menu bar and there click on tools and then visual studio android emulator and after that download the api.